# How to pass a read write datasource item from parent to child view in react-native?

Tags: listview, datasource, react-native

Using react-native, how can a parent view, pass a read-write object to a child view, where it can be modified, then have the parent view re-render when the child returns to the parent view?

I have a WaypointList ListView in a navigator.
When user selects a row, the DetailView displays TextInput's for editing.

```js
// The Parent "Master View"
var WaypointList = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function() {
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({
      rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2
    });

    return {
      itemList: this._genRows(),
      dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(this._genRows()),
      editEnabled: false,
      planLocked: false,
      selectionCount: 0,
      unitType: 0,
    };
  },

  // ToDo: Turn this into a real database datasource
  _genRows: function(): Array < any > {
    var arrayList = [];
    var waypoint = new Waypoint('Waypoint1', 0.0, 0.0, 10, true);
    arrayList.push(waypoint);
    waypoint = new Waypoint('Waypoint2', 20.0, 4.0, 10, true);
    arrayList.push(waypoint);
    return arrayList;
  },

  getDataSource: function(waypoints: Array < any > ): ListView.DataSource {
    return this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(waypoints);
  },

  selectRow: function(waypoint: Object) {
    this.props.navigator.push({
      title: waypoint.name,
      component: WaypointScreen,
      passProps: {
        waypoint: waypoint,
      },
    });
  },
});

// The Child "Detail View"
// How can I modify an object passed into the "Detail View"
// passProps appears to be read-only ?
var DetailView = React.createClass({

      textInputValue: null,

      getInitialState: function() {
        console.log('name:', this.props.person.name);
        console.log('age:', this.props.person.age);
        return {
          textDistance: this.props.waypoint.distance.meters.toString(),
          textDepth: this.props.waypoint.depth.meters.toString(),
        };
      },

      render: function() {
          return ( < View style = {
                {
                  flexDirection: 'row',
                  justifyContent: 'center'
                }
              } >
              < TextInput style = {
                styles.textInput
              }
              ref = 'distance1'
              placeholder = "Enter meters"
              editable = {
                isEditable
              }
              keyboardType = "decimal-pad"
              returnKeyType = 'next'
              onChangeText = {
                (text) => {
                  text = text.replace(/\D/g, '');
                  var meters = parseFloat(text);
                  this.setState({
                    textDistance: text
                  });
                }
              }
              value = {
                this.state.textDistance
              }
              onSubmitEditing = {
                (event) => {
                  this.refs.depth1.focus();
                }
              }
              />

      <View style={styles.separatorHorizontal} / >
              < /View>

    );
  },
});
```

I started learning react-native about 2 weeks ago yet I am no closer to figuring out a solution.

Are passProps only for read-only information?

How can read-write modification of a datasource be achieved?

Thanks in advance.

Any tips or direction are much appreciated,

-Ed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the state in the parent, and pass that state down as props to the child. When the child element changes to the new value you need, you set a callback function to the parent that resets the parent state, which in turn resets the props of any children using that value.

Check out [this](https://rnplay.org/apps/huQTKA) very basic example:

https://rnplay.org/apps/huQTKA

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TextInput
} = React;

var Parent = React.createClass({

  getInitialState() {
        return { text: '' }
    },

  onChange(text){
    this.setState({ text })
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Hello, { this.state.text }</Text>
        <Child text={ this.state.text } onChange={ this.onChange } />
     </View>
    );
  }
});       

var Child = React.createClass({
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container2}>
        <TextInput onChangeText={ (text) => this.props.onChange(text) } style={ styles.textInput }  />
        <Text>{ this.props.text }</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    marginTop:50
  },
  container2: {
    marginTop:25
  },
  textInput: {
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: '#efefef',
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: '#ededed',
    marginTop:13,
    marginBottom:13
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('Parent', () => Parent);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the example.  I am trying to understand how I can pass the onChange callback to the child when using a navigator?  I think this would need to be done inside my selectRow method

Comment: Never mind, pass callback using "passProps: { onChange: this.onChange }" and child makes callback using      this.props.onChange(this.props.waypoint);  However I cannot change this.props.waypoint in the child as it acts like it is read-only.  Instead of a callback that passes the waypoint object, do I need to make one callback method for each waypoint object field and then the parent modifies the source waypoint object?

Comment: I expect what I really need to understand is flux in order for an app to pass around a datasource to multiple views for display and modification of the datasource.  This is getting challenging quick.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ed, yes flux and redux both are great for this exact thing. They take a little bit getting used to, but once in place are very good!

Comment: Finding understandable react-native learning examples for Flux and/or redux has been a *real* challenge for this react newbie.